# Using PyMuPDF to extract images, upon export the colors in the images are inverted

Tags: image-processing, jupyter-notebook, pymupdf

PyMuPDF has successfully extracted the images from my PDF, but the colors are inverted. I followed the code from this site: https://thepythoncode.com/article/extract-pdf-images-in-python#replies

If anyone has a fix, my script looks almost identical to theirs.

Thanks!

So far I have tried to add a line that converts the CMYK to RGB, but I think the command is outdated and I could not find a new one. Here is the link for that script: https://pdf.wondershare.com/how-to/extract-images-from-pdf-python.html

Comment: Usually a problem of transparency information not correctly processed. Can you share the PDF - here or on PyMuPDF's [Discord](https://discord.gg/BZ9SF2FR) channel)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the image has been stored with transparency information. This can be determined by looking at this information:

```py
In [3]: doc = fitz.open("trans-img.pdf")
In [4]: page=doc[0]  # page shows an image having transparency channel
In [5]: page.get_images()  # 1st item base img xref, 2nd is mask xref if > 0
Out[5]: [(5, 6, 600, 728, 8, 'DeviceRGB', '', 'fzImg0', '')]
In [6]: base = fitz.Pixmap(doc, 5)  # extract base image
In [7]: mask = fitz.Pixmap(doc, 6)  # extract transparency info
In [8]: pix = fitz.Pixmap(base, mask)  # combine both
In [9]: pix.save("test.png")  # save as PNG
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will implement this and update the post!

Comment: I hope this will solve your problem.